# PHP number format with integer format

Tags: php, format, decimal

I am using `PHP` `number_format` to express prices of products, using decimal point, thousands separators, etc. For example:

```
$price = 20.456;
print "$" . number_format($price, 2, ".", ",");
```

outputs `$20.46`.

However, I would like that, if the price is integer, for example `$price = 20.00`, to output `$20`. Is there some other function or rule to achieve this, avoiding decimal points if not necessary?

Comment: I choose billyonecan solution as it is quite elegant. I thought that the function itself may have a parameter for "respecting" integers, but that not being the case, it will suffice with the if-else comparison, which in ternary form is quite elegant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do a loose comparison of `$price` cast as integer against `$price`, if they match (ie. it's a whole number), you can format to 0 decimal places:

```
number_format($price, ((int) $price == $price ? 0 : 2), '.', ',');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `$price = 20.456 +0 ;`

```
$price + 0 does the trick.

echo  125.00 + 0; // 125
echo '125.00' + 0; // 125
echo 966.70 + 0; // 966.7
```

Internally, this is equivalent to casting to float with (float)$price or floatval( $price) but I find it simpler.

Comment: but that's not the desired result, trailing zeroes should only be removed if price is a whole number

Comment: @billyonecan you can try `echo 1000000 + 0; // 1000000 `

Comment: `echo 966.70 + 0; // 966.7` - desired result would be `966.70`

Comment: Yes True. we have to write a function before we perform `+0` to price, Thanks for advice, do you have any solution for this case.?

Answer (score 3):

You can use ternary operator fot that:

```
    $price = 20.456;
    print "$" . ($price == intval($price) ? number_format($price, 0, "", ",") : number_format($price, 2, "", ","));
```

Answer (score 2):

A little helper function `my_format` to determine if the number is an integer and then return the corresponding string.

```
function my_format($number)
{
    if (fmod($number, 1) == 0) {
        return sprintf("$%d\n", $number);
    } else {
        return sprintf("$%.2f\n", $number);
    }
}

$price = 20.456;

echo my_format($price);
echo my_format(20);
```

Will output

`$20.46 $20`

Answer (score 2):

A little solution that works for any number

```
$price = "20.5498";
$dec = fmod($price, 1);
if($dec > 0)
    print "$" . number_format($price, 2, ".", ",");
else
    print "$" . floor($price);;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `floor()` function

```
$price = 20.456;
echo '$'.floor($price); // output $20
```